# CSS Floats: clear on parent does not expand it to contain floated children

Tags: html, css, css-float

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/ayyutb9j/2/) , the parent `<p>` tag contains an `<img>` tag which is floated left `float: left` however the parent `<p>` tag does not expand to fully encompass the floated `img` element although I have `clear:both` set on parent `<p>` tag.

I know that adding an extra `div` with `clear:both` before closing `</p>` or  `overflow:auto` on `<p>` will do the job but I am at wits end as to why `clear:both` set on `<p>` tag does not work as I expect.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

```css
.thumbnail-desc h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.thumbnail-desc img {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-left: initial;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail-desc p {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-desc">
  <h2>Some title</h2>
  <p>
    <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1632280/images/n-VISION-200x150.jpg" alt="Our Vision">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi nihil dignissimos. Some crazy text.Some crazy text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a 'display: inline-block;' to the '.thumbnail-desc p' and it will work. here is a example - https://jsfiddle.net/ayyutb9j/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you may misunderstand how `clear` works.

Setting `clear:both` on the `<p>` tag is telling the `p` to clear anything that comes before it - not the child items within it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` for `<p>`. Here is example: https://jsfiddle.net/hnL0gLy2/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of covering the image with a `p` tag, use a `class` and a `div`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayyutb9j/7/).

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail-desc">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<div class="outer">
<img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1632280/images/n-VISION-200x150.jpg" alt="Our Vision">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi nihil dignissimos. Some crazy text.Some crazy text
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail-desc h2 {  display: inline-block;
            background: blue;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 5px 7px;
            margin-bottom: 0; }

.thumbnail-desc img {
     float: left;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin-left: initial;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden; }
.thumbnail-desc .outer {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height:150px;
    }
```

**Why your code does not work as you thought?**

Because the `p` tag is for the text. It's height is as much as the text inside the div. For more height, you need to switch to a `div` or `span`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `.thumbnail-desc p` to the `display` of `inline-block`.